# How could I add URLs as trusted for the Azure Monitor Workbook?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, trust, azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks

How could I add URLs as trusted for the Azure Monitor Workbook?

I have a few parameters in my workbook. These parameters values are picked by the workbook user manually out of all the available in the drop downs options. These options are generated dynamically from different queries, logs, Azure resources, etc. Hence, there are a lot of combinations.

So, after a user selected some parameters I run a query in the workbook by interpolating the selected values. E.g. the user selected `a = https://, b = www.google.com/`, and I query the `{a}{b}` adress, which makes me to run the `https://www.google.com/` query.

That results in the error:

> This workbook is trying to query "https://www.google.com/", but the site is not marked as trusted. click the button "Add as trusted" below or add it to the trusted hosts section of the workbook settings.

Now, clicking the `"Add as trusted"` has the expected result. But I want to avoid to make users click the button. So, could I somehow "pre-trust" URLs I know will be used beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot pre-trust them.

That's the whole point of the trusted settings, to make sure that any user who opens the workbook knows about any calls that are leaving the azure portal.

Each user has to explicitly add them.